# Capture a exception inside a async delegate

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this code:

```
    public async Task AsyncMethod()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        });
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });
        var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception();});
        var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await AsyncMethod(); });

        try 
        {
            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            var count1 = ex.InnerExceptions.Count;
            var count2 = ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions.Count;

            throw;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I would like to understand why the count1 and count2 variables are 2 and not 3 and how can I get the third exception inside AsyncMethod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to understand why the count1 and count2 variables are 2 and not 3 and how can I get the third exception inside AsyncMethod?

`Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a basic `Task`. If you pass it an `async` delegate, then the returned `Task` only represents the beginning of the `async` method (up until the point it yields to its caller).

You should be using `Task.Run` with `async` code. `Task.Run` will create a `Task` wrapper for an `async` delegate, so the `Task` returned from `Task.Run` represents the entire `async` method.

Stephen Toub has [an excellent blog post detailing the differences between `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Also, as usr mentioned, you have problems with deadlocks whenever you block on `Task` rather than `await` it in a GUI or ASP.NET context. I have [a blog post that goes into detail about this deadlock problem](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You should use `await Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`.

So, here's your code with both changes applied:

```
public async Task AsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception();
    });
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception(); });
    var t2 = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception();});
    var t3 = Task.Run(async () => { await AsyncMethod(); });

    try 
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        var ex1 = t1.Exception.InnerException;
        var ex2 = t2.Exception.InnerException;
        var ex3 = t3.Exception.InnerException;

        throw;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You answer is more complete than mine. I recommend that it be accepted.

Comment: I tried your version of code but it doesn't hit the catch with AggregateException because the line 'await Task.WhenAll' throws a System.Exception with the .Message 'Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.'

Comment: @MuriloKunze: You're correct. I've updated the code to show an alternative way to handle exceptions with `WhenAll`.

Comment: Nice, but I notice that I can use the Task.WaitAll and then to use the AggregateException in the catch. Did you know if is htere any good reason to use WaitAll instead of 'await WhenAll?'

Comment: While this does solve the problem, why would you want to use `Task.Run` to just start another async operation in the first place?  It would be better to do as usr did and use `AsyncMethod` directly.  This is just needless overhead for the sake of symmetry in code.

Comment: I'm assuming that `async () => { await AsyncMethod(); }` is simplified code and that the real code is an `async` delegate that calls another `async` method but also does other things.

Comment: @MuriloKunze: I don't recommend blocking on `async` code because of the [possibility of deadlocks](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog. Is there any particular reason you *want* `AggregateException`? I usually avoid it, myself.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
    var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await AsyncMethod(); });
```

to this:

```
    var t3 = AsyncMethod();
```

You already *have* a task. No need to wrap it by executing it on the thread-pool.

By wrapping it you convert the `Task` that you already have (and that will fault eventually) into a `Task<Task>` that never faults (only its `Task.Result` faults). And `WaitAll` of course operates on the outer task so it never sees the exception.

It is a good technique to step through such code with the debugger to check the runtime values of all variables. It is much easier to notice this mistake that way than just by looking at the code ("looking" was enough for me because I have experience with this - but if I hadn't had experience I would have needed to run this code and debug it).

Comment: I changed it but now the catch doesn't work. If I remove the await inside AsyncMethod too, the catch works but the result is even two.

Comment: You've got an unrelated bug there: You're waiting on task which causes a deadlock in ASP.NET. Await it instead (Task.WaitAll => awit Task.WhenAny) and it will work. You might also research why waiting on tasks in ASP.NET and WinForms is a bad idea.

Comment: Part of the reason you didn't catch this is your use of `var`.  If you had to type out the variable's type it would be clear it wasn't a task, it was a task of a task.

Comment: @Servy Are you talking about t3? If I set it Task<Task<>> it doesn't compile, only Task works.

Comment: @MuriloKunze It's `Task<Task>>` not `Task<Task<>>>`.  Any `Task<T>` is implicitly convertible to `Task`, which is why that compile (but doesn't work).  If you use `var` and hover over it you can see the actual type.

Comment: Yeah, I mean Task<Task>. When I hover the var of t3, it is a Task, not Task<Task>.

Comment: @MuriloKunze in my version of the code it is a Task. In the previous it is a Task<Task>. Does this answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: @usr Now I notice that it doesn't hit the catch exception because WaitAll throws a System.Exception and not a AggregateException.